# Writing sas data to Hive with Numeric variable with More than 15 digits

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas

I am trying to write a SAS data to Hive using SAS. I have a ID variable in the table which is >15 digits long and I need to keep this variable as Numeric when I write this data to Hive. I have tried the below script but it is giving me the below warning and the values in the Hive table are truncated to 15 digits with an "e".

```
data scr.EOB_tgt(dbtype=(nacct="BIGINT"))
;
format nacct best20.
ncust $10.
;
set lat2(keep=ncust nacct bal);
run;

NOTE: SAS variable labels, formats, and lengths are not written to DBMS tables.
WARNING: Value 1589000007877656 has more than 15 digits.  It may not be accurately inserted to the BIGINT column.
```

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

I would like to be able to get the full 16 digit numeric value in the Hive table

Comment: Are they values in SAS as numbers or character strings?  SAS stores all numbers as 8 byte floating point so 16 digits is more precision than it can handle.

Comment: Did the value, 1589000007877656 , cited in the warning make it into the target dataset or not?

Comment: You might want to ask SAS support. The documentation pages https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p1rj6miqsmhercn17lz0xatfqd4l.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en  talk mainly about how to control the SAS informats used when reading data from Hadoop.  Not about controlling how data is written to Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

SAS stores all numbers as 8 byte floating point.  So you cannot represent integers with more than 15 digits exactly. To see the maximum integer that can be represented exactly use the CONSTANT() function.

```
data _null_;
  x=constant('exactint');
  put x 16. +1 x comma21.;
run;
```

Result:

```
9007199254740992 9,007,199,254,740,992
```

So if you have any ID values larger than 9,007,199,254,740,992 then you cannot store them as numbers in SAS.

Why are you storing ID values as numbers?  There is no need to perform arithmetic on ID values.

Comment: Actually this ID value is going to be used by another application which stores the ID value (nacct for this data) as numeric and conversion from numeric to string in that application is not easy, hence trying to get it uploaded into Hive as numeric

Comment: Actually, my ID value is 16 digit long only, nit 18 digit, the question is how can I transfer this data as is with 16 digit numeric variable to Hive

Comment: The note in your original post is just informational.  Check whether it actually worked. Do you have any values larger than 9,007,199,254,740,992?

Comment: Hi Tom, it didnt work, I have checked the Hive data, it is showing something like this, 1.58900000787765e15 for the above value. I want it have the full 16 digit value instead of this...